What are the Busybox od command options?
Busybox
The Busybox documentation explains only this:

od [-aBbcDdeFfHhIiLlOovXx] [-t TYPE] [FILE]
Write an unambiguous representation, octal bytes by default, of FILE to standard output. With no FILE or when FILE is -, read standard input.

But it doesn't explain what each option is and they seem to be really different from the man page
The -t option seems to not exist and gives the error:
od: invalid option -- 't'

BusyBox v1.35.0 () multi-call binary.

Usage: od [-aBbcDdeFfHhIiLlOovXx] [FILE]

The other documentation website seems to ommit the -t option and seems more accurate.

Usage:
od [-abcdeFfhiloxsv] [FILE]

Print FILE (or stdin) unambiguously, as octal bytes by default

Confirming the online documentation, when the command od --help is sent, the output is:

Usage: od [-aBbcDdeFfHhIiLlOovXx] [FILE]

Repository
So looking at the source code it seems to be some kind of remap to the od_bloaty.c source file
Question
I could not understand this source file and the documentation is not clear on all the options of the od command.
Is there some other documentation for this busybox command or some better explanation for those options?

You can use man page from another distro: https://man.archlinux.org/man/od.1

I was going to offer the POSIX text for od, but already at the start Busybox is missing -A, and has -B instead. Looks like you'll have to read the source. @GillesQuénot That Arch Linux man page also refers to GNU coreutils (and is missing at least -B), so it's likely no more accurate for Busybox than the man page at man7.org.

For some of those, there are long versions: https://github.com/brgl/busybox/blob/abbf17abccbf832365d9acf1c280369ba7d5f8b2/coreutils/od_bloaty.c#L1182 many of the rest seem to be purely formatting switches: https://github.com/brgl/busybox/blob/abbf17abccbf832365d9acf1c280369ba7d5f8b2/coreutils/od_bloaty.c#L1242

And looking at the code muru linked to, it does seem to have -A too, it's just not mentioned in that veery brief help text.

-A is an invalid option also. But I will use Busybox hexdump, it seems to be better documented.

Does man busybox 2>/dev/null | grep -A3 '^  *od ' give anything different? You should always check your local documentation first since that should always be for the version you have installed. Granted, on my system, that still doesn't give any details on what the options do, but it should in theory at least only mention options that work with yours.

It is an OS for embedded systems, so it does not have man, and it also does not appear using help od. Just the Busybox documentation od --help and it outputs Usage: od [-aBbcDdeFfHhIiLlOovXx] [FILE]

Ah, OK. Then please [edit] your question and clarify that you did check the local documentation, so the discrepancies you see aren't due to having checked the online docs for a different version. Sounds like you've found a bug, really.
